# Getting inf in a Taylor expansion for e^x, but only for small error bounds

Tags: c++, taylor-series

I am writing a program to approximate an exponential function, but I'm running into a problem. For small values of `err` the program messes up and just loops forever, getting approximations of inf every time. The program seems to be intolerant of larger and larger errors as larger `x`'s are entered. It works fine for, say, `x=1` and `err=10e-5`. As an example of when it doesn't work: `x=3` it works fine up to `err=10e-4` but when `err=10e-5` it results in inf.

```
//This program approximates e^x at a given x to a given accuracy
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
inline void keep_window_open() {char ch; cin >> ch;}
class bad_entry{};
int fac(int a) //function to find factorial
{
    int f=1; //covers 0!
    for(int w=0; w<a; ++w)
    {
        f*=(a-w);
    }
    return f;
}
int main()
{
    try
    {
        double x=0;
        double ans=0;
        double err=0;
        int n=0; 
        cout << "What number do you want to expand around?\n";
        cin >> x;
        if(!cin){throw bad_entry{};}
        cout << "What would you like the error to be within?\n";
        cin >> err;
        if(!cin){throw bad_entry{};}
        double actual=exp(x);
        while(n>=0)
        {
            ans += pow(x,n)/fac(n);
            cout << "n=" << n << '\t' << "Approx: " << ans << '\t' << "Erro: " << abs(actual-ans) << '\n';
            if(abs(actual-ans)<err)
            {
                keep_window_open();
                return 0;
            }
            ++n;
        }
    }
    catch(bad_entry)
    {
        cout << "\nINVALID ENTRY\n";
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you observe when you debug your program?

Comment: I'm using DevC++ to do this, and the debugging button isn't working with me. Also, I added an example of when it doesn't work.

Comment: `fac(n)` is almost certainly overflowing.

Comment: @roshoka -- You could have done, at the very least, print out the values of each of those calculations to see what they are before applying them to your formula.  For example, `fac(n)` as the other comment suggests, could be overflowing.

Comment: When I change `int f` to `double f` and change the output of the function from `int` to `double` it allows for smaller error bounds. So you're probably right with the overflow. Now I'm not sure how to get it to handle all possible values of error bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write a program that just prints `fac` for increasing `n` values, you'll get:

```
n=1  fac=1
n=2  fac=2
n=3  fac=6
n=4  fac=24
n=5  fac=120
n=6  fac=720
n=7  fac=5040
n=8  fac=40320
n=9  fac=362880
n=10 fac=3628800
n=11 fac=39916800
n=12 fac=479001600
n=13 fac=1932053504  // Ups - wrong - should be 6227020800
n=14 fac=1278945280  // Ups - wrong
n=15 fac=2004310016  // Ups - wrong
```

So you have an overflow already for `n` equal 13. Therefore all calculations will fail and give strange results.

If you change `fac` function to use `uint64_t` instead of `int` it will be a little better, i.e. higher `n` before overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Your "while" loop is actually divergent; you are incrementing the counter instead of decrementing.
Moreover, the "pow" function is itself implemented as "exp(y*ln(x))", which makes your implementation redundant, inefficient and imprecise.
The factorial caculation makes the complexity O(n2) which is bad. A simple increasing for loop without break, having the precision criteria as its condition clause, and incremental calculation of factorial and integer x powers would do the job.